# Replacing lines in a yaml file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, yaml, netplan

I'm trying to create a script that will replace the parameters of a given network interface in the `01-network-manager-all.yaml` file.

The file looks something like this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [195.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 195.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [196.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 196.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
    enp0s9:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [197.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 197.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
```

Say I want to replace the lines concerning `enp0s8` and leave the others as they are.

The output would look something like this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [195.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 195.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [196.250.250.125/24]
      gateway4: 196.250.250.125
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
    enp0s9:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [197.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 197.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
```

In this case, I'm looking for a `sed` - or any other command - that will replace everything in between `enp0s8` and `enp0s9`.

I'm not a very experienced Bash user, any tip will be appreciated.

My poor attempt at doing so

```
sed -e '/^ *enp0s8:/,/^ *^enp0s9:/s/$CONFIG_TO_ADD/' "/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code what you have tried to solve your own problem, adding tried code in question by OP is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: _replace the lines concerning enp0s8_ - What's the expected output?

Comment: The idea would be to change the IP configuration. It's edited for an expected output

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a tool that understands YAML instead of plain text manipulation. For example, ruby:

```sh
$ ruby -e '
    require "yaml"
    data = YAML.safe_load_file(ARGV[0])
    net = data["network"]["ethernets"]["enp0s8"]
    net["addresses"] = ["196.250.250.125/24"]
    net["gateway4"] = "196.250.250.125"
    net["nameservers"]["addresses"] = ["8.8.8.8"]
    puts data.to_yaml
' file.yml
```

```yaml
---
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - 195.10.10.10/24
      gateway4: 195.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - 196.250.250.125/24
      gateway4: 196.250.250.125
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
    enp0s9:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - 197.10.10.10/24
      gateway4: 197.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using yq :

```
yq eval '.network.ethernets.enp0s8 |= (.addresses = ["196.250.250.125/24"] |
                                       .gateway4  = "196.250.250.125" |
                                       .nameservers.addresses = ["8.8.8.8"]
                                      )' file.yml
```

Comment: Don't forget the `dhcp{4,6}` fields

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat new
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [196.250.250.125/24]
      gateway4: 196.250.250.125
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { new=new ORS $0; next }
    /^    [^ ]/ { if ( f=($1=="enp0s8:") ) print $0 new }
    !f
' new file
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [195.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 195.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [196.250.250.125/24]
      gateway4: 196.250.250.125
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
    enp0s9:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [197.10.10.10/24]
      gateway4: 197.10.10.10
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is interested.

Using `ed` if available/acceptable.

```
#!/bin/sh

ethernets=enp0s8
gateway=196.250.250.125
address=196.250.250.125/24
name_server_address=8.8.8.8

ed -s file.yaml <<-EOF
  g/$ethernets/;/nameservers/s/^\\([[:blank:]]*gateway4:[^ ]*\\).*/\\1 $gateway/\\
  -1s|^\\([[:blank:]]*addresses: \[\\).*\\(\]\\)$|\\1$address\\2|
  g/$ethernets/;/nameservers:/;/addresses:/s|^\\([[:blank:]]*addresses: \\[\\).*\\(\\]\\)$|\\1$name_server_address\\2|
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

- Change the last digit of `enp0s` if the changes should be made at the other section/block, which is pointing to `enp0s8` right now.
- Not a `yaml` parser/editor and not robust as the other solutions but It can do the job.